# JAVA Writing the diagonal of an 2-dimensional array into an 1-dimensional array

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

Want to write the diagonal of an 2-dimensional array  (n*n Matrix) into an one-dimensional array.

```html
1 2 3
4 5 6 => 1 5 9 
7 8 9
```

```
    public int[] getDiagonalFromArray(int[][] two_d_array){
    int[] diagonal_array = new int[two_d_array[0].length];   
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < two_d_array[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < two_d_array[1].length; j++) {
            for (int l = 0; l < two_d_array[0].length; l++) {  
            diagonal_array[k]=two_d_array[i][j];} //HERE SHOULD BE THE ERROR... HOW DO I CYCLE THROUGH THE 1dim "diagonal_array"? 
            }
        }
    return diagonal_array;
}
```

This method delivers wrong values.

This method of mine works, but just Prints the diagonale, instead of putting it into an 1dim array.

```
    public void getDiagonal(int[][] two_d_array){
    //int[] diagonal_array = new int[two_d_array[0].length];        
    for (int i = 0; i < two_d_array[0].length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < two_d_array[1].length; j++) {

            if (i==j) System.out.print(two_d_array[i][j]+" ");
        }
    }        
}
```

Where is the logical difference? I tried the if-clause on the first method, but it raises the "outofbound"-Exception.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1 dimension -> 1 loop. Not sure what the other two loops are for.

Comment: The first loop should not be looping to `two_d_array[0].length`, but rather `two_d_array.length`. Not sure why you have three loops? I recommend just using one of the proposed solutions below.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you need more than one loop?

```
for (int i = 0; i < two_d_array[0].length; i++) {  
    diagonal_array[i]=two_d_array[i][i];
}
```

Seems to be enough to me.

Answer (score 0):

If your matrix has the same width and height, this is a solution:

```
public int[] getDiagonal(int[][] two_d_array){
int[] diagonal_array = new int[two_d_array.length];        
for (int i = 0; i < two_d_array.length; i++) {
    diagonal_array[i] = two_d_array[i][i];
} 
return diagonal_array;
```

Comment: "If your matrix has the same width and height" - If it doesn't, there's no clear diagonal.

Answer (score 0):

Here, I consider principal diagonal elements to be the set of elements [image: Diagonal Elements], where `n` & `m` are the number of rows and the number of columns (per row?) respectively.

Thus, the number of diagonal elements is never greater than `min(numOfRows, numOfColumns)`.

And so, you can always try:

```
public int[] getDiagonalFromArray(int[][] 2DArray){
    int[] diagonalArray = new int[Math.min(2DArray.length, 2DArray[0].length]);
    int k=0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 2DArray.length && k < diagonalArray.l length; ++i) {
          for (int j = 0; j < 2DArray[i].length && k < diagonalArray.l length; ++j) {
                if (i == j) {
                     diagonalArray[k++]=2DArray[i][j];
                }
          }
    }
    return diagonalArray;
}
```

Threw in some bounds checks for good measure.

Your input matrix must at be at least rectangular (square makes most sense), otherwise, the code will behave unreliably.

This is the same as @[Andreas' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41144510/4499183), but I sacrifice performance and brevity here for the sake of understanding.